# How to deal with agreements which are made in a dependency situation?

Tags: difficult-people, jobs

I started almost at the perfect job. Still one thing is bothering me to the point where I think about changing the job or working freelance. I am working for one department and have fairly good relationship with my boss.

When the second interview took place, also the director of the facility was there and he asked me then if I also would program for him if needed. But this was clearly was not part of the job description. I said yes, just to get the job, but clearly knew and know that I don't want this.

I did not yet happen that he asked after 3 month, and hopefully it never happens, because I would not be comfortable with it and for the organisation at whole it wouldn't be beneficial if the work of the department where I am at gets interrupted (I know that the director is fully not aware of what every department does, so he probably wont see this).

For me personally, this agreement feels wrong, it bothers me, and I would like to withdraw it. But it may seem rude, or maybe the director then even doesn't want to have there anymore.
Any idea how to handle this kind of situations?

Comment: Asking "What should I do" is off-topic here. You can edit your question to try to make it on-topic (https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or you can try to post this to The Workplace https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that the thing you are worried about has actually not yet happened after 3 months.

I wouldn't worry any more about something that may not ever happen. What he said at your interview may have just been a throwaway statement. In my experience, VIPs often ask things like that. In some cases it may just be to show their importance. At one interview I was asked by the head of an organisation if I would drop whatever I was doing and help him if he had an IT problem. I answered that I would, but added that I hoped he would only ask me to do that if it was genuinely urgent. I was offered the job! (but didn't take it)

If you are faced with the situation where he asks you to do something for him, flatly refusing may hurt your career. You could perhaps explain that if you were to do it your existing workload would be affected. As director of the company though, if he wants **you** then he can probably deal with any problems arising from it clashing with your workload, maybe getting your work covered by somebody else. Important people tend to get what they want.

If it *were* to happen, say after 6 months, and if it were something that came up maybe once per year, would that be so bad?

Some people, including myself to a degree, do not like "uncertainty". I am happiest in my work when the parameters of what I have to do and how I have to do it are clearly laid out. Deviations from the norm and disruptions cause me more stress than being busy. Perhaps you are a little bit like that too?

Fact is, change is a huge factor in any tech environment. As a programmer you probably deal with change more often than you realise as technology constantly advances. Taking on the occasional ad-hoc task from your director may not be as bad as you expect. You could try and see it as a positive thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have often been asked to do stuff for my superiors that are a bit out of the scope of my position. It is not so uncommon practice in my country. The way I ended up handling it might be a bit rude but for me it worked very well.

As soon as the director asked me to do something, I would drop my normal work and start doing that and only that. I would stop answering e-mails, phone calls or whatever else. As soon as my Supervisor notices that my work is piling up and it is not getting done and asks me what is going on I would tell him that I am doing work for the Director and focusing on that because it isn't possible to do both at the same time and he should take it up with the director.

From here there are 2 likely scenarios. Either he will let you finish what you are doing and you won't need to juggle all responsibilities or he will talk to the director about him taking up your time and other critical things falling behind as a result. It is very different conversation when the team leader asks the management to not take up their resources. Either result worked for me in my case.

I know it is very dependent on position or work you are doing but after doing that two times, the third time the director asked me if I could do what he asked as paid overtime so I can tell you it is effective.

Comment: At least here in Europe work culture the more likely outcome to this approach is that you will either be replaced very soon or, if you are very good at what you are doing, that you will be treated as that difficult person that can only do one thing and never get a raise or a promotion.

Comment: @Daniel I am in Europe too but it really varies on what you do. I have stated that it might not be suitable for everyone and not saying that it is a sure win solution. It worked fine for me. You can refuse in very apologetic way and plea your supervisor to release you from the task that you can't refuse because you know ... he is the boss. You can spin it however you like.

Comment: I Agree it can work when all you want is being left alone with you main task. But you are also marking yourself as one with low soft skills and hurt your career in the long run. An like I said, it can get you out of your job pretty quickly. You are essentially playing dumb and sabotaging the organisation to get your way. some bosses don´t react well to that kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In every job I ever encountered:

1. I had to follow orders of the superiors, not only direct but also higher up.
2. I had to be willing to perform other reasonable tasks then the ones originally in the job description, if asked to.

That´s just how our economy works. Essentially you already work for your director, albeit indirect. You have to realize that any job you take will be subject to these possible changes. Even when you work for a small startup with only one boss, it could be bought out by others and you could get new assignments etc..

I would suggest you stay calm and don´t worry to much until something actually changes. When that happens you can react accordingly, for example by stating that the interruption of your current task would hurt the company or the likes. If you don´t reach an amicable agreement then, you can still look for another job. No need to worry now, when such a condition will probably never happen.